# How to use XML Path to generate a grid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to output results of a query to a grid, rather a long list of values.
What I have right now is

```
(SELECT COLUMN1+' '+COLUMN2
FROM TABLE
FOR XML PATH) AS MyGrid
```

Results I have are displayed as

```
Bob s12345 Chuck s54321
```

I would like to have them displayed as

```
Bob  s12345
Chuck s54321
```

Any help, please?

Added table records

```
CustID | CustName | StoreNumber  |   City
 ------+----------+--------------+-----------
1      |   Bob    |    s12345    |  Somewhere
2      |   Chuck  |    s54321    |  Town
3      |   Paul   |    s19285    |  BillaBong
4      |   David  |    s65478    |  North
5      |   Arnold |    s47381    |  South
```

The MyGrid ALIAS is passed to Outlook as merge field.

Comment: Can you add some test records for `TABLE`.  This will provide data to test our queries against.

Comment: added sample table. tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use cross apply with values

```
select value1,value2 from table 
cross apply
(values (value3 ,value4))b(v1,v2)
```

Comment: Tnx. I am not sure I can as the output of the entire query needs to be an ALIAS. So I am allowed to have a single column of results.

Comment: i didn't get you,can you please elaborate

Comment: added a table. Results of the query are passed as merge field to Outlook.